# does a semicolon or comma belong before "is this correct?"

Tags: grammar, questions, semicolons

You went to the store and bought chips, is that correct?

You went to the store and bought chips; is that correct?

You bought a bag of chips, correct?

You bought a bag of chips; correct?

Thanks for you help!!!

Answer (score 2):

The comma is the accepted punctuation in English for [tag questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question), such as the ones you listed.

Comment: +1 for the link to the very informative wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an "echo" question or "tag" question, so comma is incorrect.  If it were the answer:  I bought a bag of chips, correct.  If it is the question: You bought a bag of chips; correct?

Comment: Hello, Vickie. Have you a reputable source endorsing your views?